# Python Get Tags from URL

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following URL:

`http://google.com/sadfasdfsd$AA=mytag&SS=sdfsdf`

What is the best way in Python to get `mytag` from the string `~$AA=mytag&~`?

Comment: Are you sure that URL is exactly what you have? Or did you mean `http://google.com/sadfasdfsd?AA=mytag&SS=sdfsdf` (`?` instead of `$`)?

Comment: I'm curious. The 3 current answers all propose using regex to do this. Why would you do this when python has modules that can parse query strings (e.g. urlparse: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)? Granted, the regex answers are shorter, but they're not necessarily easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'http://google.com/sadfasdfsd$AA=mytag&SS=sdfsdf'
>>> m = re.search(r'.*\$AA=([^&]*)\&.*', str)
>>> m.group(1)
'mytag'
```

There is a special meaning for `$` and `&` in regex, so you have to escape those characters to tell python interpreter that these characters are literal `$` and `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `=(.+)&`

```
import re
regex = "=(.+)&"
print re.findall(regex,"http://google.com/sadfasdfsd$AA=mytag&SS=sdfsdf")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the `mytag` that comes after `$AA`, you can use this simple regex (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pQ2wX5)):

```
(?<=\$AA=)[^&]+
```

In Python:

```
match = re.search(r"(?<=\$AA=)[^&]+", subject)
```

**Explain Regex**

```
(?<=                     # look behind to see if there is:
  \$                     #   '$'
  AA=                    #   'AA='
)                        # end of look-behind
[^&]+                    # any character except: '&' (1 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to throw this one out there to show there are other ways of doing this:

```
import urlparse

url = "http://google.com/sadfasdfsd?AA=mytag&SS=sdfsdf"
query = urlparse.urlparse(url).query # Extract the query string from the full URL
parsed_query = urlparse.parse_qs(query) # Parses the query string into a dict

print parsed_query["AA"][0]
# mytag
```

See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html for documentation on the urlparse module.

NB `parse_qs` returns a list so we use `[0]` to get the first result.

Also, I have assumed the question has a typo and have amended the url so that it represents a traditional query string.