# Get string between ampersand or at the end

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Get string between ampersand or at the end

I have the following possible URLs:

```
http://google.com/sadfasdfsd&AA=mytag&SS=sdfsdf
http://google.com/sadfasdfsd&AA=mytag
```

What is the best way in Python to get mytag from the string `~&AA=mytag&~`?
There are two possibilities: `&AA=` in between or `&AA=` at the end.
Then how do I match these all with regular expressions?

This question is from:
[Python Get Tags from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208532/python-get-tags-from-url)

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'http://google.com/sadfasdfsd&AA=mytag&SS=sdfsdf'
>>> m = re.search(r'.*\&AA=([^&]*)\&.*', str)
>>> m.group(1)
'mytag'
```

But this only works when I have this type of URL:

```
http://google.com/sadfasdfsd&AA=mytag&SS=sdfsdf
```

Comment: Those are some pretty fishy looking urls -- Usually there'd be a `?` before the ampersands start popping up ...

Comment: So you want all parameters from url to be extracted if I understood correctly? Then you might want to look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074803/retrieving-parameter-from-url-in-python

Comment: If you want to use a regex, try `.*\&AA=([^&]*)\&*.*`. You're currently requiring the second `&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a URL parsing library.

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = urlparse.urlparse('http://google.com/sadfasdfsd?AA=mytag&SS=sdfsdf')
>>> url.query
'AA=mytag&SS=sdfsdf'
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(url.query)
{'AA': ['mytag'], 'SS': ['sdfsdf']}
```